# Chart object formatting errors

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I can't figure out how to correctly format dates(Xaxis),otherwise, the code below works. `MyArY()`contains dates but the dates show up with 00 year on the chart 9/1/00 for some reason?  I've tried examples I've found on the web but they didn't work for me.
Here is what the dates look like on the sheet:
`7/21/15 8:00:00 AM`
`8/25/15`
`9/1/15 12:00:00 AM`
`9/10/15`
`7/21/15`
`8/25/15`
The chart doesn't recognize the dates and they look like this:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

```
Sub Build_Chart()
'builds a chart on active sheet

Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=30, Width:=775, Top:=15, Height:=345)
objChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

End Sub

Sub Add_ChartSeries()

Dim i As Long, l As Long
Dim yAddress_ListItem As String, yAddress_ValuesRange As String
Dim xAddress_ValuesRange As String, xAddress_ListItem As String
Dim cht As Chart
Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim MyArY() As Variant, MyArX() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, iVal As Long
'Dim chSeries As Series

Dim objChartSeriesColl As SeriesCollection

With ActiveSheet '
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = .Range("B27:B" & LastRow) 'non-contiguous range
End With

Set objChartSeriesColl = objChart.Chart.SeriesCollection


If frmGeneList.lstMain.ListIndex <> -1 Then 'if listbox is NOT empty
For l = 0 To frmGeneList.lstMain.ListCount - 1
If frmGeneList.lstMain.Selected(l) Then 'identify selected items
' count of cells in that range meeting criteria
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, frmGeneList.lstMain.List(l))

' Resize arrays to hold filtered data
ReDim MyArY(1 To iVal)
ReDim MyArX(1 To iVal)

iVal = 1

' Store filtered values from that range into array
For Each aCell In rng.Cells
If aCell.Value = frmGeneList.lstMain.List(l) Then
MyArY(iVal) = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value'dates
MyArX(iVal) = aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value'numbers
iVal = iVal + 1
End If
Next aCell


xAddress_ListItem = frmGeneList.lstMain.List(l) '.Value
'defines series name

With objChartSeriesColl.NewSeries 'adds each? Series
.Name = xAddress_ListItem
.Values = MyArY
.XValues = MyArX
'.ApplyDataLabels
'.DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
'.DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0"
End With
        End If
    Next
End If

'objChart.HasTitle = True

With objChart.Chart
    '.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy;@" 'changes
'Xaxis text format
    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General" 'changes Yaxis
'Text Format
    '.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart) 'adds chart title above chart
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
'adds Xaxis title
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated) 'adds rotated
'Yaxis Title
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom) 'adds legend @ bottom
    '.ChartTitle.Text = "IonTorrent Inter-Run Viriability"  'adds chart
'title above chart
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Run Dates"
'renames Xaxis title to "X Title"
    '.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Sample Dates"
'renames Xaxis title to "X Title"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "%Alt" 'renames Yaxis
'title to "Y Title"
End With

With objChart.Chart.PlotArea.Format.Line 'adds black border around plot
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
End With

With objChart.Chart.Legend.Format.Line 'adds black border around legend
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have just started looking into  excel charts. Yours is a advanced coding. I have uploaded a sample scatter series chart with a simple routine  based on @Meehow code in one of the posts. You will notice on sheet 3 that it is possible to show correct date by aligning corresponding axis scale by a VBA routine and formatting scale axis.<https://www.dropbox.com/s/xg85k3vso5cedm6/chart3.xlsm?dl=0>       I was also facing similiar problem regarding dates. I could improve it after going through following related links.<http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2023511&seqNum=2>

Comment: Another date problem related link is from Peltier Tech Blog <http://peltiertech.com/link-excel-chart-axis-scale-to-values-in-cells/> .

Comment: I was missing `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate` line.  And now that I've activated the chart I'm using `With Activechart` and my title is showing up, however, the dates problem is still mistery to me.

Comment: Glad to note your progress. There are two problems related to dates. When I tried it was giving date of year 1900. That is the basic starting date for excel 2007 which I have. I formatted the cells to general and then entered current date by using keys ~Ctrl+;~  and copied to other cells in the range. Second issue relates to axis scale which is defined by the native features for equal spacing and minimum and maximum values. If you see in the code block a small VBA routine has been used for axis spacing using maximum, minimum and mean values of the scale range specified in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

'Converts Date to Value/Double then to Integer to truncate time
MyArX(iVal) = Int(CDbl(aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value))

This worked for me.